# In Jenkins, how to use the parallel test executor (splitTests) in a declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, parallel-testing, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I'm using declarative pipelines in Jenkins and I would like to parallelize tests. The obvious choice seems to be to use the Parallel Test Executor (splitTests) but I can't find examples or figure out the syntax to use in a declarative pipeline.

Comment: The pipeline includes this functionality for free. Just use the Parallel{} block and run whatever you want in parallel. Note that the syntax has changed with the pipeline-model-definition v1.2.

Comment: @RobHales The problem is that the documentation for the mentioned plugin is lacking. Yes, executing tests in parallel is easy. Executing 100 tests in parallel overwhelms the BlueOcean GUI and the Jenkins master. Limiting parallel execution with locks also increases execution time. Using this plugin may fix most of these issues, but nobody knows how it's working.